# I want to modify OPENCL's kernel file scrypt130511.cl,but I attempt failed

Tags: opencl

I'm mining Litecoins using an AMD Radeon HD7850 and an AMD Radeon HD4850 with cgminer.when I mined Litecoins using an AMD Radeon HD4850, Once the kernel of the time is 26ms, I want to modify the file "scrypt130511.cl" to spilt the kernel to five kernels,and once a kernel of the time is about 5ms, what can I do?

Comment: Can you show the ingredients? Maybe we look at it then suggets you something.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.I have already found the problem.